# Why do my trees share the same health?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

My trees keep on falling at the same time and i am not sure why! I am new to this unity3d javascript language so sorry in advance if its a simple fix! and here is my script in case its needed!

```
#pragma strict

//INTS
var health = 5;
//GAMEOBJECTS
var tree : GameObject;
var log : GameObject;

function Start () {

tree = this.gameObject;

}

function Update () {

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && Player_script.axehave && health >= 1 && Camera_script.tree){
health -= 1;
}

if(health == 0){
tree.GetComponent.<Animation>().Play();
Destroy();
}

}

function Destroy(){

yield WaitForSeconds(2);
Destroy(tree.gameObject);

}
```

Comment: is this a wrong place to ask this kind of a question?

Comment: well if all your trees have this script attached they will all act the same. That is, all of them will lose 1 health on Mouse0 and at some point all of them will die the same time. You need to somehow isolate a specific tree to work with.

Comment: You might have better luck asking on [Game Development SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) as the community there may be more familiar with the syntax.

Comment: thanks for the replys guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try `Camera_script.tree == tree`, or `Camera_script.tree == this.tree`.  That should change it from all trees to just the tree you want to have destroyed.

Comment: The Camera_script.tree is for checking if i am close enough to the tree so its a false or true variabel